# I can't get the entities with my query

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I was using the same procedure that I was using in my previous projects, that I learned from the tutorials provided by Google, but this time I'm getting no results..

My code is to get 3 random jokes from my datastore, which keeps only 100 jokes & to show them in a HTML table.

Here is my model:

```
class joke(db.Model):
jokeID = db.IntegerProperty()
content = db.TextProperty()
```

Here is the code in my controller in which I'm getting the entities:

```
def get(self):
deck = range(1, 101)
shuffle(deck)
items = list()
itemCounter = 0
for jokeNumber in deck:
    itemCounter += 1
    if itemCounter <= 3:
        self.response.out.write(jokeNumber)
        # I tried with fetching from the model & with GqlQuery
        #items.append(joke.all().filter('jokeID=',jokeNumber).fetch(1))
        items.append(db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM joke WHERE jokeID=:1",jokeNumber))
    else:
        break
template_values = {'items' : items}
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'index.html')
self.response.out.write(template.render(path,template_values))
```

& here is where I fill the HTML table with the data from the controller:

```
<table border="0" width="800px">
     {% for item in items %}
      <form method="post" action="/ocena">
          <tr>
            <td>
                {{ item.content }}
            </td>
          </tr> 
       </form>
     {% endfor %}
   </table>
```

In the source from the site I'm getting three empty cells, but when I execute the query in the Datastore Viewer from GAE I get the desired results..

Comment: have you tried: items.append(db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM joke WHERE jokeID=:1",jokeNumber).fetch(1)) ?

Comment: When you use GqlQuery & later you are iterating through the results you don't need to do the fetching.. but anyway, that doesn't work too, I tried now..

Comment: just a side comment: even if you make it work, it would be better if instead of the forloop, you do this: items = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM joke WHERE jokeID IN :1", deck[:3]).

Comment: If you only have 100 jokes, you really should just store them a file that you load into memory. There's no need to use the datastore.

Comment: @Nick you are right, but the idea is that in the future the system would be open so anyone could leave a joke..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've checked your example, and this code works for me:

```
def get(self):
    deck = range(1, 101)
    shuffle(deck)
    items = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM joke WHERE jokeID IN :1", deck[:3])
    template_values = {'items' : items}
    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'index.html')
    self.response.out.write(template.render(path,template_values))
```

Comment: I didn't know that GqlQuery could be used like that, from what I could find, the answers were like this one http://bit.ly/o9schi
Thanks!

Comment: `GqlQuery` is also a `Query`, and as such can be iterated to obtain results one by one. Note that this is inefficient as it requires an API call for each record. `items.fetch(3)` should be used instead.

Comment: As with the Query class, the application executes the query and accesses results either by calling the fetch() method, or by treating the GqlQuery object as an iterable. http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlqueryclass.html

Comment: @Xion Iterating over a query does one fetch for each batch - 20 records by default - not for each record.

Comment: That's good to know :) So `fetch` is only useful if you expect more than 20 records. I'd still prefer to do it anyway ("Explicit is better than implicit", they say).

Answer (score -1):

> My code is to get 3 random

```
def get_random_joke(self, category):
    jokeinfo = JokeData.all().filter("category =", category)
    return jokeinfo[random.randint(0, jokeinfo.count()-1)]
```

I think the above code would work to get one random joke from a category in the datastore if you have categories.